# Where do these random ~ (tilde) directories come from?

Tags: macos

I'm using OS X and I see these ~ directories sometime appear my directories. I know Unix and I know that ~ represents the home directory, but these other ~ directories appear elsewhere and they aren't symbolic or hard links either. What's causing this?

Comment: Some example names? Or is the name always just a lone tilde?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely that some app is trying to write files to your home directory, but the programmer has been lazy and used the '~' shorthand in the code, which won't work, instead of `/Users/<shortname>`.

The thread [Mysterious Tilde (~) Folder](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8261580th) shows how to delete it, but it comes back later on.

The thread [Mysterious Tilde Folder Appeared](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=5363926) claims that this directory is created by Apple Software Update.
If that's really the case, then this is simply a bug in Apple software, and there is no way to get rid of it permanently.

Comment: And the reason the '~' doesn't work in program code is that it's the shell (such as bash) rather than the file system routines that expands the tilde when it's used on the command line.